# how would I limit the results to only one address based on a preference

Tags: sql, oracle

Some of the donor ID's have multiple mailing addresses, and I just need to select only the first one for each donor, and if there is no mailing address tied to a donor ID, then I need to pull a billing address, and if no billing address, then shipping address. but only show one address

```
Select d.donor_id, d.firstname,d.lastname, da.address_type_cd,address,
(da.city || ',' || da.state_province_cd || ' ' ||da.zip_postal_cd) as city_state_zip
from donor d
inner join donor_address da
on d.donor_id = da.donor_id
where da.address_type_cd = 'MAILING';
```

Comment: Can a donor have ***at most*** one address of each kind? Or can they have two mailing addresses, for example? I understand that they may have a mailing address and a billing address etc., but for that you explained the order of preference. But if a donor can have two mailing addresses, which one should be chosen? Would either one work equally well?

Comment: They just need to have one address period, but the preference is mailing, billing, shipping. if that helps

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.  How do you distinguish amongst the different types of addresses?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this. Note the *outer* join - to make sure donors that don't have an address are still shown in the result set (with `null` address columns). If this is not desired, change the join to *inner* join.

**DATA FOR TESTING**

```
create table donor (donor_id primary key, firstname, lastname) as
  select 101, 'Mia' , 'Soleno' from dual union all
  select 102, 'Ali' , 'Omer'   from dual union all
  select 108, 'Chen', 'Li'     from dual union all
  select 105, 'Ed'  , 'Torre'  from dual
;

create table donor_address (donor_id, address_type_cd, 
             address, city, state_province_cd, zip_postal_cd) as
  select 101, 'BILLING' , '33 Donor Lane', 'Boston' , 'MA', '83882' from dual
  union all
  select 101, 'BILLING' , 'Other Rd A/B' , 'Lebanon', 'MO', '30238' from dual
  union all
  select 101, 'SHIPPING', '132 Main #44' , 'Boston' , 'MA', '83877' from dual
  union all
  select 102, 'MAILING' , '4332 1st St.' , 'Austin' , 'TX', '23408' from dual
  union all
  select 102, 'SHIPPING', 'Lake Villa'   , 'Austin' , 'TX', '23411' from dual
  union all
  select 108, 'BILLING' , 'First Street' , 'Fresno' , 'CA', '92002' from dual
  union all
  select 108, 'MAILING' , '8 Last Street', 'Fresno' , 'CA', '92002' from dual
;
```

**QUERY AND RESULT**

```
with prep as (
  select donor_address.*,
         row_number() over (partition by donor_id
            order by case address_type_cd when 'MAILING'  then 1
                                          when 'BILLING'  then 2
                                          when 'SHIPPING' then 3 end) as rn
  from   donor_address
)
select d.donor_id, d.firstname, d.lastname, p.address_type_cd,
       p.address, p.city, p.state_province_cd, p.zip_postal_cd
from   donor d left outer join prep p on d.donor_id = p.donor_id and p.rn = 1
order  by donor_id
;

DONOR_ID FIRSTNAME LASTNAME  ADDRESS_ ADDRESS       CITY    STATE_ ZIP_POSTAL_
-------- --------- --------- -------- ------------- ------- ------ -----------
     101 Mia       Soleno    BILLING  33 Donor Lane Boston  MA     83882      
     102 Ali       Omer      MAILING  4332 1st St.  Austin  TX     23408      
     105 Ed        Torre
     108 Chen      Li        MAILING  8 Last Street Fresno  CA     92002
```

Comment: I think you nailed it! Thank you so much. Now I am going to research how this works so I better understand it.  What doe the phrase "with prep as" do in this instance?

Comment: @JeffreyBaker - "prep" is an alias for a subquery. As is the case whenever we give an alias to a subquery, it's whatever name I want to give it - it has no particular meaning, other than to me and to whoever reads the code; it's a reminder that this subquery "prepares" the data for the final query. The main thing in that fragment is the keyword `with`. If you asked this question, it means that perhaps you are not familiar with the **`with` clause** (in SQL - not specific to Oracle), which is used to declare and define a subquery at the top of your code. You need to study it separately.

Comment: Thank you for that. I am new to SQL in general and have just started using oracle. This really helps me understand it, and I will for sure study that more. I appreciate your help so very much

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care which address you'll display, take *any* (for example, `MIN` or `MAX`). Such as:

```
select 
  d.donor_id, 
  d.firstname,
  d.lastname,
  max(da.city || ',' || da.state_province_cd || ' ' ||da.zip_postal_cd) as city_state_zip
from donor d inner join donor_address da on d.donor_id = da.donor_id
where da.address_type_cd = 'mailing'
group by d.donor_id, d.firstname, d.lastname;
```

---

Your query contains `employees` and `address` *things*; I'm not sure what they represent. I guess they might be comments. If not, and if they are additional columns, add them into the `GROUP BY` clause.

---

Based on your comment, saying that you want to select

- mailing address
- billing address
- shipping address

whichever exists first. In that case, consider nested `NVL`s. Simplified:

```
select donor_id,
  nvl(mailing_address, nvl(billing_address, shipping_address))
from ...
```

Comment: I updated my question a little, I didn't make it clear enough to start

Comment: OK, I think I now understand what you want. I added some more info into the answer; have a look, please.

Answer (score 0):

Allow all addresses in the subquery and add ROW_NUMBER analytic function to order the adresses for each donor_id (see `partition by`) based on the preference (highest preference  -> `rn = 1`).

Preferably add additional columns to the `order by` clause, so that the ordering is unique and the result is deterministic

```
Select d.donor_id, d.firstname,d.lastname, da.address_type_cd,address,
(da.city || ',' || da.state_province_cd || ' ' ||da.zip_postal_cd) as city_state_zip,
row_number() over (partition by d.donor_id order by decode(da.address_type_cd,'MAILING',1,'BILLING',2,'SHIPPING',3), da.zip_postal_cd,....) as rn
from donor d
inner join donor_address da
on d.donor_id = da.donor_id
where da.address_type_cd in ( 'MAILING','BILLING','SHIPPING')
```

Than use a second query and select only the address with `rn = 1`

```
with adr as (
  ... copy here the query from above ...
)
select * from adr
where rn = 1
```

Comment: I am having trouble figuring out where to add the rn=1. Thank you for all the help, I am so new at this